# How to create a Splunk alert using Terraform?

Tags: terraform, splunk

I want to create an alert in Splunk using Terraform.

It's apparent that this should be done using resource type [splunk_saved_searches](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/splunk/splunk/latest/docs/resources/saved_searches), but every example that I've seen creates a report rather than an alert.

I'm using Terraform provider [splunk/splunk](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/splunk/splunk) version 1.4.22.

What's the simplest resource configuration that will create an alert?

Comment: This was previously raised as a GitHub issue on the provider: [Saved Search Alert Creation Not Populating in Alerts page](https://github.com/splunk/terraform-provider-splunk/issues/79). [One of the provided answers](https://github.com/splunk/terraform-provider-splunk/issues/79#issuecomment-901537023) was a great hint that helped me narrow the search.

Comment: [Downvotes on questions are free.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down)

Answer (score 2):

I saved the exact same search as both a report and an alert.  The savedsearches.conf stanzas are below.  The last settings are those needed for an alert.  Your actions and schedule, of course, will be different.

```
[Metrics Report]
action.email.useNSSubject = 1
action.webhook.enable_allowlist = 0
dispatch.earliest_time = -15m
dispatch.latest_time = now
display.visualizations.show = 0
request.ui_dispatch_app = search
request.ui_dispatch_view = search
search = index=_internal component=Metrics

[Metrics Alert]
action.webhook.enable_allowlist = 0
alert.suppress = 0
dispatch.earliest_time = -1w
dispatch.latest_time = now
display.visualizations.show = 0
request.ui_dispatch_app = search
request.ui_dispatch_view = search
search = index=_internal component=Metrics
# The rest are needed for an alert
alert.track = 1
counttype = number of events
cron_schedule = 0 6 * * 1
enableSched = 1
quantity = 0
relation = greater than
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of this conf language. The docs might be useful: [savedsearches.conf](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/admin/savedsearchesconf)

Answer (score 0):

There are over 150 arguments to choose from.

The critical argument that seems to be missing from examples that I've seen is:

> `is_scheduled` - (Optional) Whether this search is to be run on a schedule

[Reports can run on a schedule](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Report/Schedulereports) too, so the point here is that multiple conditions must be met when creating an alert.

```
resource splunk_saved_searches myalert {
    name = "myalert"
    search = "index=*" // a basic search query
    is_scheduled = true // this is the lynchpin for 'Alerts' vs 'Reports'
    cron_schedule = "*/13 * * * *" // a prime frequency might be useful
    dispatch_earliest_time = "-15m" // not required, but typically used
    dispatch_latest_time = "now" // apparently "now" is not the default
    actions = "track" // "track" is arbitrary, but don't leave this emtpy
    alert_track = true // this is the most basic alert action
}
```

Comment: Both reports and alerts can and do run on a schedule so `is_scheduled` is not a determining factor.

Comment: @RichG, Based on my testing, `is_scheduled` makes all the difference. It's possible that this is a Terraform provider issue -- I don't know. I just know what my experimentation and testing turned up after many failed attempts at creating an alert with [Terraform](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform).